# Execute program in Geany produces geany_run_script.sh script

Tags: geany

I had to reinstall my Java compiler a while back, so I know I broke something. Now when I execute a program in Geany (pressing F5) it produces a `geany_run_script.sh` script in my working directory. The contents of the script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

rm $0

java "boltzmann"

echo "

------------------
(program exited with code: $?)"         


echo "Press return to continue"
#to be more compatible with shells like dash
dummy_var=""
read dummy_var
```

...this should be run a terminal automatically, but isn't. I poked around in the Preferences, but couldn't determine where to fix this. Suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating run_script is default behaviour. This is due some issue running inside internal vte might cause. However, you can configure it: Edit->Preferences->Terminal->"Don't use run script" (Execute programs in vte has to be enabled for it. Therefor you will need have libvte installed)